# Starting at new line when pressing enter in VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS 2015 and when I press enter after a code line when writing javascript I always start the next line at the beginning. I would like it to start at the "proper" place, for e.g.

```
    function newLine() {
        Starts here..//Works fine
    }
Starts here now..
```

EDIT: By "Should start here.." I mean one tab in from the braces, not two lines below :)

Comment: For me this works as you want to (that is the cursor goes to "Should start here.."). I write "function newLine() {". VS will add "}" and the cursor will be placed in between the brackets. If I press enter the cursor is in the right place (one tab in on the next line).

Comment: @Rosted I've updated the example..It works fine when writing the first brace and then press enter, but otherwise it always starts at the beginning

Comment: Anyone solved the issue? I have got the same problem but with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: No sorry. Havn't found anything

Answer (score 11):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor ->  -> Tabs -> Indenting To BLOCK.

Answer (score 4):

VS 2015 suddendly stopped indenting properly for me. I was able to solve this by going to Tools/Options/Text Editor/"language of choice"/Tabs and selecting smart indenting

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Choose your language -> Tabs -> Indenting -> Smart

Finally you must restart the Visual Studio(all instance).